# How can I handle for a specific CommandInvokeError? [DIscord.py]

Tags: error-handling, discord, discord.py

One of my functions can cause a `KeyError` error to be raised. This raises a `CommandInvokeError`. However, there are other errors, like `DivisionByZero` that can cause the `CommandInvokeError` to be raised. I only know one way to handle errors and it's:

```
@cmd.error
async def cmd_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send("Error!")
```

This is going to be the same for any error that causes a `CommandInvokeError`. How can I make it so that It only sends the message if a `KeyError` is raised?

Note: this is in a cog

Comment: A good thing would be to handle those errors with a `try/except` block instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@cmd.error
async def cmd_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        if isinstance(error.original, KeyError):
            await ctx.send("Error!")
```

You can also use `error.__cause__`, it makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks! PS: what do you mean I can also use `error.__cause__` ? What part of the code would I implement it?

Comment: @Ethitlan `error.__cause__` is simply an alias for `error.original`. So you could do: `if isinstance(error.__cause__, KeyError)`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!